# How to Airdrop images from my iPhone to my computer to avoid JPEG compression?

Tags: macos, iphone, airdrop

When I transfer images from my phone to my computer, I believe they are converted to JPEG and compressed.

I don't want lossy compression, the full resolution images are worth more to me than a few kilobytes on my disc. I don’t know if I can control this.

How can I transfer images with 100 percent quality and resolution?

Comment: Airdrop doesn't offer any such setting about compression. You can try saving to Files first, and then Airdrop it, or wait it to sync. Make a dedicated folder for such task and keep freeing it every few weeks.

Comment: Question... believe based on what?